# ARPlaneAnchor never added to the scene on an iPhone8

Tags: ios, ios11, arkit, iphone-8, iphone-8-plus

Does anybody else also experience non-working ARKit scene on an iPhone8?

When I download Apple's [ARKit example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality) and run it on an iPhone8, it stays on  *Initializing* - when I check the `ARSCNViewDelegate` implementation:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.statusViewController.cancelScheduledMessage(for: .planeEstimation)
        self.statusViewController.showMessage("SURFACE DETECTED")
        [..]
    }
    [..]
}
```

It seems as if it never goes beyond the guard, so a `ARPlaneAnchor` is never being added to the scene...

The same project on an iPhone6s / iPhone7 runs just fine though...

Does anyone else know how to fix this?